# Computer won't turn on after Shutdown, If I didn't unplug from the Power Supply

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, shutdown

After the normal Shutdown, if the power supply is ON, I can't get it to start up. If I try within ten seconds or a couple of minutes it's working. **But if I try after a five minute or so, the light is on, the fans are running but nothing comes on the screen. Not even bios is starting.**

But, If I do clean the RAM and Reconnecting all the wires goes from SMPS to Motherboard. It suddenly starts working.

I'm confused about what is causing the issue.

Comment: What OS? What model PC? What doe you mean by "clean the RAM"?

Comment: I'm running OpenMediaVault. It's not specifically with this OS. The same happens with Windows as well. Cleaning the RAM Means rubbing the RAM Contacts with Pencil Eraser. It's Dual Core Processor @2.93GHz | 4GB DDR2 RAM. Not sure about Motherboard

Comment: Cleaning with an eraser is a *bad* idea. It leaves particles & removes thin gold plate.

Comment: Oh my bad. Now using Fine Cloth pieces.

Comment: Don't "clean" and your RAM. You are damaging components. Your computer has a hardware fault and needs competent local expertise to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

This *kinda* sounds like your BIOS is not entering an S5 state completely, and thus can't return to S0 all the way.  I used to get this with old chipset drivers, and also old buggy BIOSes. Once in a while it's a sign of a failing MB southbridge/northbridge (old systems) or electrolytic capacitors that are going stale.

Confirm hardware issues by booting to a linux live install, and doing shutdowns/restarts.

I'd recommend backing everything up REGULARLY to redundant destinations and trying different chipset drivers, then a BIOS update if you're familiar with flashing BIOS/UEFI.  Even dump the BIOS/UEFI 2 or 3 times in separate files first so you can take the .bin to a shop if you get stuck with a bad flash.